# Using a String variable to dynamically add SVG to ImageView

Tags: java, android

Basically, I'm trying to add an SVG drawable to an ImageView, but I keep getting strange type errors I can't resolve.

```
// String var "icon" holds the name of the drawable resource
int drawableId = context.getResources()
     .getIdentifier(icon, "drawable", MainActivity.PACKAGE_NAME);

// drawableId shows the error:
// 'getDrawable(android.content.Context, int)' in 'android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat' cannot be applied to '(int)'
// I tried using Context instead of ContextCompat, but I got an error about needing API 21
Drawable channelIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(drawableId);

// drawableId here shows no error
imageView.setImageResource(drawableId);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Basically this is a workaround for needing to use a variable for `R.drawable.something`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to add an SVG drawable to an ImageView

`ImageView` does not support SVG.

> Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Beyond the aforementioned issue, replace:

```
Drawable channelIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(drawableId);
```

with:

```
Drawable channelIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
```

Comment: I forgot to specify I was using an SVG as the background to the ImageView not the src. I suppose I could use a TextView also... but thanks, your solution fixed it!

Comment: Thought I did. Sorry :)